# Generic type constraint and variance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am building a simple type mapper similar to AutoMapper but with a more dynamic behaviour. The caller can decide to filter `RecordStatus == RecordStatus.Deleted` records when mapping from entity framework models.

Abstract mappers:

```
public interface IMapper<in TIn, out TOut>
{
    TOut Map(TIn input);
}

public interface IRecordStatusFilterable
{
    string RecordStatus { get; }
}

public abstract class RecordStatusFilterableMapperBase<TIn, TOut> : IMapper<TIn, TOut>
{
    private readonly bool _filterDeletedRecords;

    protected RecordStatusFilterableMapperBase(bool filterDeletedRecords)
    {
        _filterDeletedRecords = filterDeletedRecords;
    }

    protected bool FilterDeletedRecords
    {
         get { return _filterDeletedRecords; }
    }

    public abstract TOut Map(TIn input);
}

public class MultiLookupValuesMapper : RecordStatusFilterableMapperBase<IEnumerable<Lookup>, string>
{
    private static readonly Func<Lookup, bool> _predicate = 
        filterable => filterable.RecordStatus == RecordStatus.Active;

    protected MultiLookupValuesMapper(bool filterDeletedRecords) : base(filterDeletedRecords)
    {
    }

    public override string Map(IEnumerable<Lookup> input)
    {
        var inputList = input as IList<Lookup> ?? input.ToList();
        if (!inputList.Any())
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (FilterDeletedRecords)
        {
            inputList = (IList<Lookup>)inputList.Where(_predicate);
        }

        return string.Join(", ", inputList.Select(l => l.Value));
    }
}
```

Concrete Mappers:

```
public class FooMapper<TRecordStatusFilterable> : RecordStatusFilterableMapperBase<Foo, FooViewModel> 
    where TRecordStatusFilterable : class, IRecordStatusFilterable
{
    private readonly IMapper<IEnumerable<TRecordStatusFilterable>, string> _multiLookupValueMapper;

    public FooMapper(IMapper<IEnumerable<TRecordStatusFilterable>, string> multiLookupValueMapper,
                     bool filterDeletedRecords) : base(filterDeletedRecords)
    {
        _multiLookupValueMapper = multiLookupValueMapper;
    }

    public override FooViewModel Map(Foo input)
    {
        return new FooViewModel
        {
            // Error here
            BarLookupValues = _multiLookupValueMapper.Map(input.Lookups)
        };
    }
}
```

Entity Framework model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ICollection<Lookup> Lookups { get; set; }
}

public class Lookup : IRecordStatusFilterable
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string RecordStatus { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModels:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    // ICollection<Lookup> => string
    public string BarLookupValues { get; set; }
}
```

I got a compile error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Lookup>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TRecordStatusFilterable>'

But my `Lookup` class does fulfill the generic type parameter constraint as it implements `IRecordStatusFilterable`. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: `Lookup` is a class that satisfies the constraint but it is not the `TRecordStatusFilterable` type which is a place holder for whatever concrete type is supplied. There is no guarantee that `Lookup` is compatible with the generic argument type when an instance is created.

Comment: May I ask why? `_multiLookupValueMapper` is of type `IMapper<IEnumerable<TRecordStatusFilterable>, string>` and I called `_multiLookupValueMapper.Map` with a `ICollection<Lookup>`. Why isn't this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a lot of the code is irrelevant to the actual problem. Here is a simpler version that, hopefully, illustrates it better:

```
class MyList<T>
    where T : class, IConvertible
{
    private List<T> list = new List<T>();

    public void Add(string s)
    {
        list.Add(s); // error
    }        
}
```

Yes `T` is constrained, and `string` fits the constraints, but that doesn't mean you can go and add `string` to a List of arbitrary T's. That wouldn't type safe.

If I defined

```
class Bar : IConvertible { /* left out IConvertible impl */ }
```

and made a `var bars = new MyList<Bar>()` it is obvious that adding a string to bars is a problem for that code in the generic class.

You've just got a more complex version of this and I'm not 100% sure what exactly you are trying to express. Perhaps the class `FooMapper` shouldn't be generic at all and should just take an instance of `IMapper<IEnumerable<Lookup>, string>`.

Comment: Sorry for the irrelevant code, I thought it would provide more context to my problem. I will try to change my `FooMapper` implementation to be concrete instead of generic. Thanks!

Comment: @rexcfnghk it's OK. I didn't mean it to be dismissive.  You provided a good amount of detail.